# pandas postgres binary: No module named indexes.base

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, pickle, psycopg2

I am trying to retrieve pandas dataframes from a postgresql database. I wrote these dataframes into the database as binary, via:

```
PANDAS_DATAFRAME = cPickle.dumps(PANDAS_DATAFRAME, -1)
```

and the sql INSERT INTO statement then writes:

```
psycopg2.Binary(PANDAS_DATAFRAME)
```

into the database.

I basically used a trick there to register a psycopg2 Binary type as follows:

```
def cast_pickle(data, cur):
    if data is None: return None
    return cPickle.loads(str(psycopg2.BINARY(data, cur)))

psycopg2.extensions.register_type(
    psycopg2.extensions.new_type(
                psycopg2.BINARY.values, 'BINARY-PICKLE', cast_pickle))
```

However, when I now try to recover the binary data with

```
sql_cmd = "SELECT * FROM THE_TABLE" 
sql_db_pd = pandas.read_sql_query(sql_cmd, psycopg2.connect(**params))
```

I get the error: **No module named indexes.base**
when *cPickle.loads(str(psycopg2.BINARY(data, cur)))* is executing (see above).

When I downgrade pandas from 0.2 to 0.18 retrieval works without any problem. I don't get why it should be a pandas problem and what I can do about it.